# python and mysql connections in a class , DB open and close strange behaviour

Tags: python, mysql, magento

I have written a small app that uses mysql to get a list of products that need updating on our magento website.

Python then actions these updates and marks the product in the db as complete.

My Original code (pseudo to show the overview)

```
class Mysqltools:
    def get_products():
       db = pymysql.connect(host= .... )
       mysqlcursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
       sql = select * from x where y = z
       mysqlcursor.execute(sql % (z))
       rows = mysqlcursor.fetchall()
       mysqlcursor.close()
       db.close
       return rows

    def write_products(sku, name, id):
       db = pymysql.connect(host= .... )
       mysqlcursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
       sql = update table set sku = sku, name = name, id = id.....
       mysqlcursor.execute(sql % (sku, name, id))
       mysqlcursor.close()
       db.close
```

This was working ok, but on each db connection string we were getting a pause.

I did a bit of research and did the following:

```
class Mysqltools:
    def __init__():
        self.db = pymysql.connect(host= .... )

    def get_products():

       mysqlcursor = self.db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
       sql = select * from x where y = z
       mysqlcursor.execute(sql % (z))
       rows = mysqlcursor.fetchall()
       mysqlcursor.close()

    def write_products(sku, name, id):
       mysqlcursor = self.db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
       sql = update table set sku = sku, name = name, id = id.....
       mysqlcursor.execute(sql % (sku, name, id))
       mysqlcursor.close()
       db.commit()
```

This has a MASSIVE speed improvement. However, it would only do a successful get_products on the first iteration, once it was called a second time, it was finding 0 products to update, even though performing the same SQL on the db would show a number of rows returned.

Am I doing something wrong with the connections ?
I have also tried moving the db = outside of the class and referencing it but that still gives the same issue.

**UPDATE**

Doing some testing, and if I remove the `DictCursor` from the cursor I can get the correct rows returned each time (I've just created a quick loop to keep checking for records)

Is the DictCursor doing something I am unaware of ?

** UPDATE 2 **

I've removed the DictCursor, and tried the following.

1. Create a while True loop which calls my get_product method.
2. In MySQL change some rows so that they should be found.

If I go from having 0 possible rows to find, then change some so they should be found, my code just shows 0 found, and loops stating this.

If I got from having x possible rows to find, then change it to 0 in mysql, my code continues to loop showing the x possible rows.

Comment: I've attempted to do this as per these instructions [link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200522/how-to-deal-with-database-connections-in-a-python-library-module/200529#200529?newreg=690df926733d4c82945a52efcf2e6419)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer to this is as follows:

```
db = pymysql.connect(host=.... user=... )

class MySqlTools:
    def get_products():

       mysqlcursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
       sql = select * from x where y = z
       mysqlcursor.execute(sql % (z))
       rows = mysqlcursor.fetchall()
       mysqlcursor.close()
       db.commit()
```

This then allows you to re-use the db connection and remove the overhead of creating and closing a connection each and every time.

In testing, downloading 500 orders from our website and writing them to a db went from 16minutes to <3 minutes.